# Accessing Fitbit Intra-Day Time Series with httr: Invalid redirect_uri

Tags: httr, fitbit

I try to access Fitbit intra-day time series data. When I execute the code below, I always get the following error: "***Developer information: invalid_request - Invalid redirect_uri parameter value***".

```
require(httr)

Sys.setenv("HTTR_SERVER_PORT" = "1410/")

fitbit.app <- oauth_app("[MyAppName}", key = "[MyClientID]", secret = "[MySecret]")

fitbit.ep <- oauth_endpoint(
  request = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token",
  authorize = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize",
  access = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token"
)

fitbit.token <- oauth2.0_token(fitbit.ep, 
                               fitbit.app, 
                               scope=c("heartrate"),
                               use_basic_auth = T)
```

I configured my app under https://dev.fitbit.com to have a callback URL "http://localhost:1410/".

The same problem was described here: https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API-Development/Having-trouble-with-redirect-uri-via-httr-in-R/m-p/1286028/highlight/false#M5194. But the answer flagged as a solution there does not work.

Also, I wonder why "response_type=code" is set, instead of "response_type=token" as I would expect. I tried to set the extra parameter *type = "token"*, but that doesn't change it.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, fortunately I found the problem myself. The answer might be useful to somebody else as well.

I compared the authorization URL from the code above with the one generated by a Fitbit helper page: https://dev.fitbit.com/apps/oauthinteractivetutorial.

This indicated that the httr-derived redirect_uri contained the suffix "%2F" two times in a row. That means, the encoded redirect_uri was "http://localhost:1410//" instead of "http://localhost:1410/". The solution is to substitute

```
Sys.setenv("HTTR_SERVER_PORT" = "1410/")
```

by

```
Sys.setenv("HTTR_SERVER_PORT" = "1410")
```

in the code above. Of course, I found the code fragment of setting the environmental variable to "1410/" somewhere in the net. There it was said that it was the central key to get things working. That's life.

I hope that will help others. This damn fitbit API already caused me a lot of headache.